# Define a relation $R$ on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows: $(x,y) \in R \iff (x-y)(x^{2} + y^{2} - 1) = 0$.

Tags: proof-verification, equivalence-relations

Question:

Define a relation $R$ on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows: $(x,y) \in R \iff (x-y)(x^{2} + y^{2} - 1) = 0$. Is this an equivalence relation?

My attempt:

Reflexive ?

$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, (x-x)(x^{2} + x^2 - 1) = 0$. So $(x,x) \in R$. Hence the relation is reflexive.

Symmetric?

If $ \ (x,y) \in R \implies (x-y)(x^2 + y^2 -1) = 0 \implies -(y-x)(x^2 + y^2 -1) = 0 \implies (y-x)(y^2 + x^2 -1) = 0 \implies (y,x) \in R$.

Hence, symmetric.

Transitive?

I don't think its transitive since $(-1,0) \in R, (0,1) \in R$ but $(-1,1) \notin R$.

Is my approach and proof correct?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Excellent! Good job.

Comment: The approach is correct. In fact, all you need is the last part which disproves transitivity (of course, when first starting the question, you don't know it isn't an equivalence yet, so you wouldn't have skipped trying to show reflexive and symmetric).

Comment: Good on the OP for showing a faithful and solid attempt.  This is a fun relation to think about because $x$ and $y$ are related when $(x,y)$ lives on the diagonal line $y=x$ or the unit circle.  This geometric way of thinking makes reflexivity and symmetry pretty clear, but transitivity not so much.  And, of course, $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ lie on the circle but $(-1,1)$ does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that there is nothing wrong with doing what you did for the question, but all you need to say is:

> Because $(-1, 0) \in R$, and $(0, 1) \in R$ but $(-1, 1) \notin R$, $R$ is not transitive. Hence $R$ is not an equivalence relation.

Otherwise, everything is correct. But keep in mind there are tradeoffs between comprehensiveness and conciseness.

Comment: @amWhy: I updated the answer to make it more "neutral".

Comment: Well done, @Dair.